# Where to find the code of a standard Java class?

Tags: class, awt, java

For example, I would like to see the code of the class Line2D in the package java.awt.geom. How can I find it?

Comment: http://jdk7.java.net/source.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to jdk home folder. There will be a folder named `src`. In that you will get source code of all the inbuilt java classes.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk<version>\src\java\awt\geom\Line2D.java
```

Probably you might be having `src.zip` folder. You can unzip it.

Comment: The JRE does not contain src.   Also the file extension on that seems suspicious.

Comment: @RohitJain. You are right, I am a noob and I was wrong. :) I'll edit the title.

Comment: @RohitJain. You anticipated me. :) However, I have to wait for a few minutes before accepting the answer.

Comment: @RohitJain. No, it is the website which does not allow me to accept the answer immediately.

Comment: @RohitJain. Done. Thanks again for the quick help!

Answer (score 0):

You have one implementation at OpenJDK http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/

Answer (score 0):

If you have JDK, it's a file named `src.zip` inside JDK root folder.

Common 32bits location:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk<version>\src.zip`